# What value is not strictly equal to itself & NaN in javascript

Tags: javascript, nan

I need that value of a variable such that i get alert "Yes", in the code.

```
var a;

// set the value of a here ...
a=?

// don't edit the code below:
if (a === a) { 
    alert('No!'); 
} else {
    if (isNaN(a)) {
        alert('Not again!');
    }
    else { 
        alert('Yes');
    }
}
```

What is a?

Comment: Is this a quiz question?

Comment: what is the issue here? how will `if(a===a)` ever be false I fail to understand.

Comment: I'm not aware of any case other than NaN, which is not to say such an exotic case does not exist. Why does it matter? If this is a job interview question, you should withdraw your application to such a company that asks irrelevant trivia questions.

Comment: The first part of your if statement, `if(a === a){...`, will **always** resolve to true and nothing else will be evaluated. What are you trying to check with that comparison?

Comment: How is this a 'programming problem'?

Comment: @EdgarSanchez No, NaN is NOT === NaN.

Comment: but NaN doesn't pass the 2nd if, so it's obviously not the answer. Even though this is obviously a test/homework/interview question (if it's the third, do yourself a favor and decline any offers you get) I'm curious as to the actual value that produces Yes

Comment: I bet it is an interview question, but to say they should walk away because of it is ridiculous. Not everyone has the luxury position of walking away from interviews because they don't like a question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
n = 0;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'a', { get: function() { return n++; } });

> a === a
< false
```

Comment: I was thinking on similar lines about a function having a side effect on some global variable. But, I could not think of a way that a function can be called while reading a variable. Thanks for the tip of using a 'property'...

Comment: @torazaburo : literally outstanding...my brain was stopped at NaN only.
@skbhardwaj.india : For node.js use `GLOBAL` instead of `window`.

Comment: @torazaburo: thanks a ton! Also, can you please tell me the reason as to why this solution is working fine for the first run only. If I'm again execute the same code, i'm getting an error "TypeError: can't redefine non-configurable property 'a'". [I am executing the code on firebug console.]

Comment: @skbhardwaj.india To be able to re-execute, please add the property `configurable: true` to the property descriptor along with `get`.

Comment: `var a = NaN;`//redefinition of isNaN
`window.isNaN = function isNaN(p){
    if (p == NaN){ return true;}
    else{return false;}
};`

Answer (score 0):

First, thanking @skbhardwaj.india for asking the question and thanking @torazaburo for answering the question.

Inspired by @torazaburo's answer, I would like to be independent of external/global variable hence using closures.

> Object.defineProperty(window, 'a' , { get: (function(p){ return
>   function(){ return p++; }})(0)  });